# Hypothesis of the Going-Down Theorem

Tags: commutative-algebra

In [Atiyah-Macdonald](http://www.math.toronto.edu/jcarlson/A--M.pdf), the Going-Down Theorem (listed as Theorem 5.16) assumes the integral extension to be a domain, which is due to the usage of a lemma (listed as Proposition 5.15). However, it seems to me nowhere in the proofs of both theorems used this assumption, so I wonder if it can be removed.

Comment: to quote the proof in A & M,  "$K$, the field of fractions of $A$".

Comment: ya, but the extension B doesn't have to be a domain, does it